# Express, Ejs and i18next how to switch between languages?

Tags: express, ejs, i18next

I have been trying to figure out how to make the switcher or language selector work from the frontend part of the website. Also my first time working with SSR, so I am not sure about the communication in between. So far what I handled and works well, the inclusion for the translation rendering is working, also when i manually change the language for testing purpose.

I have been reading the documentation, but there is not specific tutorial about how to handle this, more than the function "changeLanguage" and some solutions I found are  older as 5 years and involves, deprecated version and some kind of extra library to handled some template views, and I don't know if if this actually is still feasible. However inside the [repository from i18next-http-middleware](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware/tree/master/example), there is an example that basically does kind what I want. So can be found under the "basic-pug" folder. The difference is that it is used "Pug" as a template engine, which I don't think it should affect or make any difference. so I used exactly the same configuration as the example, which i downloaded and tested and it was working, so it supposed enabled a cookie, and then on the url can pass the cookie as a param, with the locale, and it supposed to work, however not working with in my project, and I also wondering if it possible to have "/de/" instead "/?lang=de", example [www.myweb.com/de/about](http://www.myweb.com/de/about) and not [www.myweb.com/about/?lang=de](http://www.myweb.com/about/?lang=de), because that's not exactly what I was imagining, and also no clear how to handled when u have nested or several routes.

In general, I was wondering how to use the "changelanguage" function in the frontend side, so I have, for example, something like:

```
<div>
<div onclick="Changelanguage("de")"> Deutsch</div>
<div onclick="Changelanguage("en")"> English</div>
</div>
```

Because by declaring the function just like in the views, on a script tag, I the changelanguage is not a function, because there is no communication between both.

Please find below my configuration:

Json file:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "project",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js --exec \"node -r dotenv/config -r @babel/register\"",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && mkdir -p dist && babel src -s -D -d dist",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "graphql-request": "^4.3.0",
    "i18next": "^21.9.1",
    "i18next-fs-backend": "^1.1.5",
    "i18next-http-middleware": "^3.2.1",
    "locomotive-scroll": "^4.1.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^1.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  }
}
```

My routes file js

```
import { GraphQLClient
} from "graphql-request";
import { Router
} from "express";
import * as queries from "./queries";
import i18next from "i18next";

const routes = Router();

export function request({ query, variables, preview, includeDrafts
}) {
// ...some headers and client configs
};

  return client.request(query, variables);
}




let generalInfo = null;


const getData = async (options) => {
  options.page = options.page ? options.page : "";
  if (!generalInfo) {
    generalInfo = await request({
      query: queries.getGeneralInfo,
      variables: {
        locale: options.lang
        }
    });
}
  let q = queries.getPage(options.page);
  let data = await request({
    query: q,
    variables: {
      locale: options.lang
    }
});
  data = Object.assign(data, generalInfo);
  return data;
};

const getCase = async (slug, lang) => {
  if (!generalInfo) {
    generalInfo = await request({
      query: queries.getGeneralInfo,
      variables: {
        locale: lang
        }
    });
}
  slug = slug ? slug : "";
  let q = queries.getCase;
  let data = await request({
    query: q,
    variables: {
      locale: lang
    }
});
  data = Object.assign(data, generalInfo);
  const filter = data.allCases.filter((n) => n.slug == slug)
  return filter;
};

const getInnerPage = async (slug, lang) => {
  if (!generalInfo) {
    generalInfo = await request({
      query: queries.getGeneralInfo,
      variables: {
        locale: lang
        }
    });
}
  slug = slug ? slug : "";
  let q = queries.getInner;
  let data = await request({
    query: q,
    variables: {
      locale: lang
    }
});
  data = Object.assign(data, generalInfo);
  const filter = data.allPages.filter((n) => n.slug == slug);
  return filter;
};

routes.get("/cases/:slug", (req, res) => {
  let slug = req.params.slug;
  getCase(slug, req.locale).then(filter => {
    if (filter.length) {
      res.render("case",
        { title: filter.project_title, filter, t: i18next.t
        });
    } else {
      res.render("404");
    }
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
});
});




routes.get("/page/:slug", (req, res) => {
  let slug = req.params.slug;
  getInnerPage(slug, req.locale).then(filter => {
    if (filter.length) {
      res.render("page",
        { title: filter[
                0
            ].titlePage, filter, t: i18next.t
        });
    } else {
      res.render("404");
    }
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
});
});

routes.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let options = { 'lang': req.locale, 'page': ""
}
//console.log(req.locale + " locale selected");
  getData(options).then(data => {
    res.render("home",
    { title: "Home", data, t: i18next.t
    });
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
});
});

export default routes;
```

My index js

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import logger from "morgan";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import routes from "./routes";
import sassMiddleware from "node-sass-middleware";

import i18next from "i18next";
import i18nextBackend from "i18next-fs-backend";
import i18nextMiddleware from "i18next-http-middleware";


const { PORT = 5050 } = process.env;
const app = express();


i18next.use(i18nextBackend)
  .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    //lng: 'de',
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    preload: ['de', 'en'],
    backend: {
      loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}/translation.json'
    },
    detection: {
      order: ['querystring', 'cookie'],
      caches: ['cookie'],
      lookupQuerystring: 'lang',
      lookupCookie: 'lang',
      ignoreCase: true,
      cookieSecure: false
    },
  })


app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next));



//i18next.changeLanguage('de');



app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "../views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.locals = { config: { whatever: 'this is' } };

app.use(
  sassMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, "../public/scss"),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, "../public"),
    indentedSyntax: false, 
    sourceMap: false
  })
);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
app.use("/", routes);


app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.status(404).render('404.ejs');
});

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.status(500).render('500.ejs');
});



app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

export default app;
```

Thank you in advance for any help, I think I am mainly struggling because I use to work on client side, but still learning about SSR.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define the language also in the route, like described here: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware#language-detection

Define the 'path' in the detection options: `order: ['path', /*'session', */ 'querystring', 'cookie', 'header'],`

Regarding the language change. You probably just need to navigate to the route with the appropriate language.